# Any known issues migrating from Debian to Red hat or CentOS (due to data centre move)?

Tags: centos, debian, rhel, system-administration

Are there any known issues/compatibility concerns moving hosted domains, websites (mainly CMS systems Fatwire, Drupal, WordPress) from a Debian OS to either Redhat or Cent OS? This is due to changing data centre providers.

Answer (score 0):

With some effort the migration should work out fine. I'll share some common questions to save you some Googling.

Most visible differences between Debian and Red Hat to sysadmins:

- Service Management: `update-rc.d` on Debian becomes `chkconfig` on Red Hat. At least they'll unify on `systemctl` with System D eventually.
- Apache configuration: `a2ensite` and `/etc/apache2/` on Debian becomes `/etc/{conf.d,conf.modules.d}` on Red Hat
- Network Interface Configuration: `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian becomes `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` on Red Hat
- Package Management and Software Installation: see [RPM DPKG Rosetta Stone](http://itrs.tw/wiki/RPM_DPKG_Rosetta_Stone)